# Displaying the battery discharging notification in a larger font through settings for configurable greater chance of user charging phone in response

Tags: notifications, battery, charging

It would be nice if there were a way in the Android settings to display the battery discharging notification in large or extremely large letters.

This is because when the notification is displayed, especially, when in the middle of an intensive task, or when in between an intensive task with someone else or when working as part of a group, we simply tend to ignore it and dismiss it.

Instead, if the notification text was presented as larger text, it would increase, first, our level of alertness, and, then, our level of engagement, with such notification.

In such cases we would put the battery to charge, in situations, where we might ignore it (and end up with a phone with a discharged battery).

It is also true that such a notification would be easier on visually impaired users, which are also likely to increase their responsiveness to a discharged battery, and charge it.

In the case TalkBack was enabled it would be good if the notification stuck to the screen, so the user, could then hear, it, several times (because they might forget what they hear, and then dismiss it by hovering over it and double tapping).

When will this functionality be supported?

How can I enable such functionality on my Android phone?

Thank you for your support.

Thank you for your feedback.

Thank you for your answers.